# Error when using javascript querySelector but no error when using jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Rather than using jQuery I would like to use Vanilla JavaScript to complete a tutorial I found online, but when I use querySelector('.form') I receive the following error message "app.js:29 Uncaught TypeError: formEl.form is not a function", however when I use jquery $('.form') the error is gone! I can't seem to understand why this error is apparent when using pure JavaScript but is not when using jQuery's selector when they're both selecting the same DOM element.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

    // Chat platform

    const chatTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#chat-template').outerHTML);
    const chatContentTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#chat-content-template').outerHTML);
    const chatEl = document.querySelector("#chat");
    const formEl = document.querySelector('.form');
    //const fE = $('.form');

    const messages = [];
    let username;


// Local Video

    const localImageEl = document.querySelector('#local-image');
    const localVideoEl = document.querySelector('#local-video');

// Remote Videos

    const remoteVideoTemplate = Handlebars.compile(document.querySelector('#remote-video-template').outerHTML);
    const remoteVideosEl = document.querySelector('#remote-videos');
    let remoteVideosCount = 0;


// Add validation rules to Create/Join Room Form

   formEl.form({
        fields: {
            roomName: 'empty',
            username: 'empty',
        },
    });


    // create our WebRTC connection

    const webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
        // the id/element dom element that will hold "our" video
        localVideoEl: 'local-video',
        // the id/element dom element that will hold remote videos
        remoteVideosEl: 'remote-videos',
        // immediately ask for camera access
        autoRequestMedia: true,
    });

// We got access to local camera

    webrtc.on('localStream', () => {
        localImageEl.style.display = 'none';
        localVideoEl.style.display = '';

    });


});
```

Comment: For this you can't swap out the jQuery version for vanilla.  jQuery has a lot of extra stuff under the hood, and `.form` is one of those.

Comment: You must have some jQuery plugin for that `form()` method. Will need to convert it

Comment: Is there a javascript method equivalent to jQuery's form() method I can use? I really don't want to have to rely on jQuery.

Comment: Vanilla js elements don't have a function called `form`. Jquery is not used only to select elements, it has a lot of other things

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `form()` method in it's core. That is probably an external plugin. Look in whatever scripts are included for something related to forms

Comment: You need to figure out what jQuery `.form` does (it's not a standard jQuery function, clearly an addon - you'd know which one), and write code to do it